# Replace openstack controller node?

Tags: openstack

CPU utilization is high on openstack controller node.

I want to know how to replace the controller node or any other way to fix this issue.

I dont find any documentation for this online. Need help.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help without any information at all? How did you deploy openstack? Which processes utilize CPU the most? What have you tried yet to mitigate the impact?

Comment: I didnt deploy openstack. I am working on a project where openstack was installed by previous workers who are not working anymore. 
RabbitMQ is utilizing more memory. the environment is at max capacity so all the compute nodes, RabbitMQ and DB keep the CPU utilization at 90% all the time because of which nuetron service fails sometimes and nova is unable to communicate with controller nodes most of the times.

need to find the complete step by step process to replace controller node.

using Kilo version of the openstack.

we usually restart all the services to get things back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a new Node as a Controller node, HA setup
- After new Controller works and enough (a strong Node), deactivate first one.

Comment: I didnt deploy openstack. I am working on a project where openstack was installed by previous workers who are not working anymore. RabbitMQ is utilizing more memory. the environment is at max capacity so all the compute nodes, RabbitMQ and DB keep the CPU utilization at 90% all the time because of which nuetron service fails sometimes and nova is unable to communicate with controller nodes most of the times. need to find the complete step by step process to replace controller node. using Kilo version of the openstack.